# Run a script several times in terminal

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I have a file script.sh that contains a specific command that I want to run. 
Every time I do ./script.sh I execute this script. This script contains a unique identifier, for example:

```
... load id_1 /path ...
```

What I want to do is to run this script n times using different ids.
For example the first time it run it will use id_1, the second one id_2 and so on.
How can I do that?

Comment: How do you specify that ID? As a command line parameter?

Comment: Let's say that i just want the id to be unique. So  a number from 0 to N that is the number of times I want to run the script is fine. No need to specify it by command line. Simply 0,1,2,3 ... N-1 can be fine as ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script.sh file contains entry like you have posted:

> ... load id_1 /path ...

Then one option is to edit it and replace 1 with $1 as listed below:

> ... load id_$1 /path ...

Run this bash one liner from your shell:

```
$ for i in $(seq 1 10); do ./script.sh $i ; done
```

**some explanation**

seq will print a sequence of numbers e.g. 1 to 10

For example, the below command will print digits from 1 to 100 on your shell

> $ seq 1 100

Next is ./script.sh $i

It will pass value of variable $i, created while cycling seq, to script.sh

The instruction id_$1 inside your script.sh will replace $1 with value passed to it from one liner